# Combined column data display only unique value

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This is my source table. I want to combined column data and display unique data only.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DUMMY;

PLAN_CD              PLAN_NM              CLASS
-------------------- -------------------- ------
D01501               DENTAL               AA
D01501               DENTAL               AB
D01501               DENTAL               AC
V01501               VISION               AA
V01501               VISION               AB
```

And i want to ouput like this.

```
PLAN_CD              PLAN_NM              
-------              --------
D01501               DENTAL,AA,AB,AC              
V01501               VISION,AA,AB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PLAN_CD,
       LISTAGG(PLAN_NM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PLAN_NM)
  FROM
    (
    SELECT PLAN_CD,
           PLAN_NM AS PLAN_NM
      FROM DUMMY
    UNION 
    SELECT PLAN_CD,
           CLASS AS PLAN_NM
      FROM DUMMY
    )
GROUP BY PLAN_CD
ORDER BY PLAN_CD;
```

Comment: Thanks Teja for giving solution.But it will work on oracle 11g. But now i am working on oracle 10g. Give me solution for oracle 10g.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one please help me.Whatever output i want please give me like this only and again i am telling i am using oracle 10g. Give me solution for oracle 10g. Thanks in advance